# Remove image classes from post thumbnail output

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, customization

I wish to remove the image classes generated by default in the output whenever post_thumbnail() is called -

```
<img width="1024" height="768" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/example-1024x768.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="Yet another example">
```

I've read a bit about the remove_action() filter and this seems the way to go but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: this is untested. but what would happen if you did the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => ''));

Comment: Thanks, tried it out but didn't work. If nothing is set it seems to default to "attachment-xlarge wp-post-image"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this in your `functions.php`:

```
//remove class from the_post_thumbnail
function the_post_thumbnail_remove_class($output) {
        $output = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $output);
        return $output;
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'the_post_thumbnail_remove_class');
```

Comment: Applying this the image is not output. Maybe there's just a typo somewhere?

Comment: there was a syntax issue with the `preg_replace` I changed the code accordingly. [Here's the source of the code.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-post-thumbnail-classes)